# Add EnvironmentObject in SwiftUI 2.0

Tags: swift, swiftui

Since SwiftUI 2.0 does not have an AppDelegate and SceneDelegate anymore, where should EnvironmentObjects be set?

This how it was done previously, where do i have to add them now?

```swift
window.rootViewController = UIHostingController(rootView: ContentView()
                             .environmentObject(settings))
```

Comment: There is an adaptor property wrapper for app delegate that allowing you to use a custom AppDelegate class.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try the following:

```
@main
struct TestApp: App {
    @StateObject var settings: Settings = ... // init here

    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
                .environmentObject(settings)
        }
    }
}
```