# How we can notify ObservableObject about changes of its initializers?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have a ObservableObject-Class which inside this class, I got a published var with name of **persones**! I do initialize it with some data called: ***allData***.

Then I try to update my ***allData*** with action of a Button, and this action apply the wanted update to my ***allData***, but my published var has no idea, that this data got updated!

How we can make published see the new updated ***allData***?

```
struct PersonData: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    var name: String
}

var allData = [PersonData(name: "Bob"), PersonData(name: "Nik"), PersonData(name: "Tak"), PersonData(name: "Sed"), PersonData(name: "Ted")]

class PersonDataModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var persones: [PersonData] = allData
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var personDataModel = PersonDataModel()

    var body: some View {
        VStack
        {
            Button("update allData") { allData = [PersonData(name: "Bob")] }

            HStack
            {
                ForEach(personDataModel.persones) { person in Text(person.name) }
            }
        }
        .font(Font.title)
    }
}
```

PS: I don´t want use .onChange or other things for this, I would like this happens internally in my class.

Also I know I can use down code for this work, but that is not the answer

```
personDataModel.persones = [PersonData(name: "Bob")]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having a top-level property (outside of any class or struct) is probably not a good idea. I don't see the whole picture, but it looks like your app needs a global state (e.g., a `@StateObject` initialised on the `App` level). Consider this answer:

- [Add EnvironmentObject in SwiftUI 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63172953/8697793)

---

If you really need to observe your array, you need to make it *observable*.

One option is to use [CurrentValueSubject](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine/currentvaluesubject) from the `Combine` framework:

```
var persons = ["Bob", "Nik", "Tak", "Sed", "Ted"].map(PersonData.init)
var allData = CurrentValueSubject<[PersonData], Never>(persons)

class PersonDataModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var persones: [PersonData] = allData.value

    private var cancellables = Set<AnyCancellable>()

    init() {
        allData
            .sink { [weak self] in
                self?.persones = $0
            }
            .store(in: &cancellables)
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var personDataModel = PersonDataModel()

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button("update allData") { 
                allData.send([PersonData(name: "Bob")]) 
            }
            HStack {
                ForEach(personDataModel.persones) { person in 
                    Text(person.name)
                }
            }
        }
        .font(Font.title)
    }
}
```

Comment: @Omid I recommend this article: https://heckj.github.io/swiftui-notes/ (it's long but helpful).

Comment: thanks a lot, but I would bother you more with my Questions! LoL

Answer (score 0):

The `allData` is copied into `persones` at initialization time, so changing it afterwards does nothing to `personDataModel`. After `StateObject` created you have to work with it, like

```
Button("update allData") { 
   self.personDataModel.persones = [PersonData(name: "Bob")] 
}
```

Comment: I know that personDataModel.persones is the way to go, but I got this idea that IN THIS CODES for me allData is like a bank of data, which it has everything there, and even personDataModel.persones should watch the change of allData, I do not know if we can add some line of codes to class for this job, that updated of allData make update to persones as well

Answer (score 0):

I think you're doing something wrong.

if you want to update all your views, you have to pass the same object with `@EnviromentObject`.

I don't know your storage method (JSON, CORE DATA, iCloud) but the correct approach is to update directly the model

```
class PersonDataModel: ObservableObject
{
    @Published var persones: [PersonData] = loadFromJSON //one func that is loading your object stored as JSON file

    func updateAllData() {
        storeToJSON(persones) //one func that is storing your object as JSON file
    }
}


struct ContentView: View {
    
    @StateObject var personDataModel = PersonDataModel()
    
    var body: some View {

        VStack
        {
            Button("update allData") { 
                self.personDataModel.persones = [PersonData(name: "Bob")] 
             }
            
            
            HStack
            {
                ForEach(personDataModel.persones) { person in Text(person.name) }
            }


 
        }
        .font(Font.title)
        .onChange($personDataModel.persones) {
             persones.updateAllData()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks, see your codes, you did all the things write, But you updated personDataModel.persones with .onChange! The all point of my question, is writing kind of class which could understand the changes of source data. In your giving code change of loadFromJSON. We have lots of power working with @StateObject after parsing data, I wanted to know if we code write kind of class which finish the job before we start taking care of it. in other word you change your source of JSON to other, class do get notice it and initialize it to persones. I want to know if this thing is possible?

Comment: I don't understand very well your request. I develop an app in SwiftUI that is managing a lot of data and is working like this (of curse with async update). Could you explain with a example diagram flow ore something else what is your goal?

Comment: How we can make published see the new updated allData inside its class? @pawello2222 already gave the answer